# Ubuntu linux 32 bit eclipse product is not working in 64 bit Ubuntu linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a created a eclipse product from 32 bit Ubuntu Linux machine and I was able to launch it in the same machine without any issues.

I have copied the same build in to Ubuntu 64 bit Linux machine and tried to launch the executables. It is failing to launch the tool. It is not showing any errors at all. When I double click on the exe nothing will happen. JRE with the 32 bit machine is bundled with the Tool. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you have a 64 bit Java you must use a 64 bit build of your product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a 32-bit executable file on a 64-bit multi-architecture Ubuntu system, you have to add the i386 architecture and install the three library packages libc6:i386, libncurses5:i386, and libstdc++6:i386

Comment: installed ia32-libs and then tried to launch the application and its works in 12.04 ubnuntu